# Is it possible to display an Image in an autocompletion-popup list (Gtk3)

Tags: image, python-2.7, autocomplete, gtk3

I am using an `Entry` with an `EntryCompletion` opbject that has a `ListStore` model.
For each record in the model, there is an image I would like to display in the autocomplete-popup list.

How can this be done?
Is it possible to add a `Gtk.CellRendererPixbuf` column to the model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interesting enough I could not find any examples of this yet it turns out to be possible and not insanely complicated. Lets start with a small image of the goal which uses icons for convinces reasons.
[image: Example of auto-completion with icons]

So how do we get there, first we create the `ListStore` containing a column with strings to match on and a icon-name to convert into a pixbuf (this could also be a pixbuf directly).

```
    # Define the entries for the auto complete
    entries = [
        ('revert', 'document-revert'),
        ('delete', 'edit-delete'),
        ('dev help', 'devhelp'),
        ]

    # Setup the list store (Note that the data types should match those of the entries)
    list_store = Gtk.ListStore(str, str)

    # Fill the list store
    for entry_pair in entries:
        list_store.append(entry_pair)
```

Next step is setting up the `EntryCompletion` and linking it with the `Liststore`

```
    # Create the Entry Completion and link it to the list store
    completion = Gtk.EntryCompletion()
    completion.set_model(list_store)
```

Now the magic, we need to create 2 renderers, one for the text, one for the pixbufs. We then pack these in the completion to add columns to it.

```
    # Create renderer's for the pixbufs and text
    image_renderer = Gtk.CellRendererPixbuf.new()
    cell_renderer = Gtk.CellRendererText.new()

    # Pack the columns in to the completion, in this case first the image then the string
    completion.pack_start(image_renderer, True)
    completion.pack_start(cell_renderer, True)
```

In order to make sure the renderers use the the correct column we here specify which column from the `ListStore` the renderers should read. For the `image_renderer` we set the `icon_name` attribute as we give it icon names. If we would feed it `Pixbuf`'s we would need the `pixbuf` instead.

```
    # Set up the renderer's such that the read the correct column
    completion.add_attribute(image_renderer, "icon_name", 1)
    completion.add_attribute(cell_renderer, "text", 0)
```

As there are no multiple column we need to tell the completion which column contains the string. In our case column 0.

```
    # Tell the completion which column contains the strings to base the completion on
    completion.props.text_column = 0

    # Create the entry and link it to the completion
    entry = Gtk.Entry()
    entry.set_completion(completion)
```

And that's it!

Comment: [Here](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2009/08/howto-an-introduction-to-gtk-treeviews-and-autocompletion/2/)  is an example.

Comment: Nice find! I couldn't find any examples back when I wrote this answer :)